# C# Windows Service fails to start fast enough

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a C# Windows Service. The `OnStart()` method contains 3 lines that all they do is start a thread. The class itself has no static objects that would cause a delay. It is as simple as a service can be. My code is signed by a self made key.

**Edit:** I just figured out that assembly isn't signed, the rest are. It uses a few assemblies which are signed but the service itself isn't.

This code is running inside a virtual machine, whenever the host is running slow and this VM is booting up, the service will fail to start with this error:

> A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the ServiceName service to connect.

Setting the service to delay start fixes it but it's a long delay and it's very annoying. Has anyone else had this problem with .NET services (2.0)?

The OnStart method:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Thread startThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartThread));
    startThread.IsBackground = true;
    startThread.Start();
}
```

The StartThread method, in which all I do is call another class so that the OnStart won't have to wait for static variable initialization or for the constructor method to end.

```
private void StartThread()
{
    Worker mainThread = new Worker(this);
    mainThread.RunWorker();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What does the thread do?  Is is initializing data with huge DB queries?  Is it connecting to another TCP/IP client/server?

Comment: Show us the code in `OnStart`

Comment: The thread does a lot of stuff but it's on a different class and the class doesn't get instantiated or statically called until the thread is running.

Comment: I am editing to add the code.

Comment: @mntgoat, have you tried my suggestion about the signing?

Comment: No I have not yet. That will be one of my next tests.

Comment: @casolorz 5 years on, have you had any further insights regarding this issue?  I am experiencing precisely the same errors on my test VMs under load, and `OnStart()` is basically identical to yours above.  Did you ever figure out a definitive cause?

Comment: @khargoosh sorry I don't remember much about this problem and no longer work where I had that code. Sounds like having a mix of singed and unsigned assemblies might have been part of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is most likely due to the strong name signing that you have on your executable. In general, it's not good practice to do that on executables ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4fa028b%28VS.100%29.aspx)). I have also experienced the same problem in one of my projects, where an executable took an incredible amount of time to start, and turned out it was due to strong name signing the executable (.NET 2.0 as well).

Comment: I just figured out that assembly isn't signed, the rest are. It uses a few assemblies which are signed but the service itself isn't.

Comment: I do have a rollingfile appender with log4net, not sure if that could cause the problem.

Comment: You might try to but some trace messages here and there and try to see how far the app gets. In my case the onstart code wouldn't even get executed.

Comment: I tried that with the logger and yeah not even the main method would get in. I really think it might be the signing thing, maybe the other assemblies that have signing are affecting the loading?

Comment: I tried moving the log4net initialization until much later and it didn't help.

Comment: try removing all signing, and see what happens :)

Comment: Just tried it. Still failed. I'm going to try not logging and no strong names now.

Comment: I removed all strong names. Also I removed all log4net from that service. It got better but it still failed once during my testing. I tested several times. I can't really have it fail not even once. I wish the "restart on failure" stuff would work with it. I guess I will have to try other stuff.

Comment: One approach you could try is remove all the references from your service executable, just have it barebones.. and then incrementally add things to it and see at point where it fails.

Comment: Well mostly yes. Removing all strong names, and removing all references to log4net prior to the OnStart method makes it work most of the time. For it to fail the system has to be running so slow that a lot of Microsoft stuff fails too, so I am not too worried about it. At one point it was so slow the services panel wouldn't even open, it would give me some sort of timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

Consider turning AutoLog = false. I've seen where this flag can cause the timeout you're describing.